# Definition of equivalence of quadratic forms.

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition, quadratic-forms

I am reading *A Course in Arithmetic* by J-P Serre. Definition $7$ on page $32$ says

> Two quadratic forms $f$ and $f'$ are called equivalent if the corresponding modules are isomophic.

I am not sure what modules Serre is referring to. What would be the overlying set, which is made up of these equivalence classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question.  A quadratic form $Q$ is always defined on an $A$-module $V$, where $A$ is a commutative ring (cf. p. 27).  A *quadratic module* (also known as a *quadratic space*) is just a pair $(V,Q)$, where $V$ is a module and $Q$ is a quadratic form on $V$; this definition is also given on p. 27.

In this definition, Serre simply defines two quadratic forms $Q, Q'$ on $A$-modules $V, V'$ to be *equivalent* if the quadratic modules $(V,Q)$ and $(V',Q')$ are isomorphic.  (A *morphism* of quadratic modules is an $A$-linear map $f: (V,Q) \to (V', Q')$ such that $Q' \circ f = Q$; this is also defined on p. 27.)